# Printf() while using system calls

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

The homework problem I am working is pretty simple, but I'm new to C so I may be getting stuck on syntax errors. What I am trying to do is call a program from a different program, assign a new process using `fork()`, and then wait on the child to finish using `waitpid()`. I am trying to A. get `waitpid()` to work, and B. get a simple test message to show after the child is finished.

./countprimes is being ran remotely through ./countmaster. ./countprimes works fine, that just prints to the screen all of the primes from x to y. ./countmaster calls ./countprimes.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

         int processid = fork();
         int status;
         char* arguments[4];
         arguments[0]="./countprimes";
         arguments[1]="10";
         arguments[2]="30";
         arguments[3]=NULL;

         if(processid == 0)
                  execvp("./countprimes",arguments);
         else
                  waitpid(processid, &status, 0);
                  printf("test1");
}
```

I would expect to see:
         count primes instance starting at 10 and ending at 29
         count primes instance for 10 to 29 is 6
         test1

what I see instead is no test1 message. I also get a gcc warning: implicit declaration of function 'waitpid'; did you mean 'getpid'?

Comment: You should *always* use `{  }` around blocks of statements (as after `if`, `else`, `while`, `for`, ...), even if the block only contains one statement. You will see why it is a good thing to get into that habit when looking at your code. (C does not consider *indentation* to be significant.) ;-)

Comment: The warning about `waitpid` is because you did not include the header file declaring that function. Try to add `#include <sys/wait.h>` in the beginning.

Comment: @DevSolar I very strongly disagree. Coding style is a judgement call. Increasing code clutter decreases readability, which decreases maintainability. If I just `return` immediately after a check in a `void`-returning function, I'm not going to be using curly braces unless I'm working at a company/on a project that requires it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see few syntax mistakes and a missing header:

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

             int processid = fork();
             int status;
             char* arguments[4];
             arguments[0]="./countprimes";
             arguments[1]="10";
             arguments[2]="30";
             arguments[3]=NULL;

             if(processid == 0) {
                      execvp("./countprimes",arguments);
            } else {
                      waitpid(processid, &status, 0);
                      printf("test1");
            } 
    }
```

Comment: This worked to remove the compiler error. However I don't understand why I can never seem to get the printf() statement to work. I have tried to add the printf() statement every other line of this code, and I never once got it to print. Any advice?

Comment: @RobertMunroe That's strange because I can run the code and see the printf output.